# Why this alert returns undefined

Tags: javascript

```
alert(0==false);   //true; as expected
alert("a"[0]);     //a; as expected
alert("a"[false]); //undefined; why?
```

So why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you a trying to access a property via bracket notation, the value of the expression is converted to a **string**. Thus, `"a"[false]`, really is `"a"['false']`, and `"a"[0]` is actually `"a"['0']`. Both property names are obviously very different..

In `0==false`, `false` is converted to a **number** which is indeed `0`.

---

In other words: `Number(false)` and `String(false)` produce two different values, and thus, even though `0 == false`, `"a"[0] !== "a"[false]`.

Answer (score 3):

The string `"a"` only has a `0` index, the first and only character.

`0 == false` is `true`, as `0` is falsy, but `0 === false` is `false` as they are not the same type, and passing `false` as the index doesn't make it the number `0` even if they both evaluate to falsy, which is why it's `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript object has a 0 index only.

So

```
"a"[0] //'a'
"a"[1] //undefined
"a"[false] //undefined
```